# Asp Hyperlink and Website link?

Tags: c#, asp.net, literals

I have a hyperlink in an aspx page, whose value is set in the code-behind. The C# code creates website link and sets the NavigateUrl to the URL. The problem is, when the link is clicked, the site address gets appended to existing website address.

e.g.
www.cnn.com   <- main site which has hyperlink.
Let's say the new link is 'www.fox.com', when the link is clicked, I get an error, because now the page address looks something like this:

www.cnn.com/www.fox.com

Is there anyway to just display the link which I set behind the code.

```
ASPX page:
 <asp:Hyperlink ID="ltrWebsite" runat="server"/> 

C#:
ltrWebsite.NavigateUrl = "www.fox.com";
ltrWebsite.Text = "www.fox.com";
```

Thanks.

Comment: Are you or are you not using a [`HyperLink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.hyperlink.aspx) control? I don't know how this even compiles, as `Literal` doesn't even have a `NavigateUrl` property.

Comment: yes, does not compile ! I was just testing this for him.

Comment: So, do you just want to display the link, or also make it clickable? Your question is very ambiguous.

Comment: sorry i was using Hyperlink not literal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in markup cannot be a literal, it has to be an hiperLink:

```
<asp:HyperLink ID="ltrWebsite" runat="server"/>
```

in code behind do not forget the **http://** prefix:

```
ltrWebsite.NavigateUrl = "http://www.fox.com";
ltrWebsite.Text = "www.fox.com";
```

Comment: not possible, edit you question with your new markup and codebehind please :)